# Location of Angular CLI or TypeScript with -g (global)

Tags: typescript, ubuntu

When we install Angular CLI or TypeScript in Ubuntu using terminal,

npm install -g angular-cli

OR

npm install -g typescript

What does "-g" do? (I know it means globally installation). I want its location on my computer. I need to change content on "tsconfig.json" file. How would I do it?